# spark and mill - create an additional task that creates a filtered assembly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mill

I want to build a `mill` job that allows me to develop and run a Spark job locally either by `SparkSample.run` or having a full fat jar for local tests.
At some point of time I'd like to send it as a filtered assembly (i.e. without all spark related libs, but with all project libs) to a cluster with a running Spark Context.

I currently use this `build.sc`

```
import mill._, scalalib._
import mill.modules.Assembly

object SparkSample extends ScalaModule {
  def scalaVersion = "2.12.10"
  def scalacOptions =
    Seq("-encoding", "utf-8", "-explaintypes", "-feature", "-deprecation")

  def ivySparkDeps = Agg(
    ivy"org.apache.spark::spark-sql:2.4.5"
      .exclude("org.slf4j" -> "slf4j-log4j12"),
    ivy"org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.16",
    ivy"org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.16"
  )

  def ivyBaseDeps = Agg(
    ivy"com.lihaoyi::upickle:0.9.7"
  )

  // STANDALONE APP
  def ivyDeps = ivyBaseDeps ++ ivySparkDeps

  // REMOTE SPARK CLUSTER
  // def ivyDeps = ivyBaseDeps
  // def compileIvyDeps = ivySparkDeps
  // def assemblyRules =
  //   Assembly.defaultRules ++
  //     Seq(
  //       "scala/.*",
  //       "org.slf4j.*",
  //       "org.apache.log4j.*"
  //     ).map(Assembly.Rule.ExcludePattern.apply)
}
```

For running and building a full fat jar, I keep it as is.

For creating a filtered assembly I comment the `ivyDeps` line under "STANDALONE APP" and uncomment everything below "REMOTE SPARK CLUSTER".

I felt editing a build file for a new task is not very elegant, so I tried to add a separate task to `build.sc`

```
  def assembly2 = T {
    def ivyDeps = ivyBaseDeps
    def compileIvyDeps = ivySparkDeps
    def assemblyRules =
      Assembly.defaultRules ++
        Seq(
          "scala/.*",
          "org.slf4j.*",
          "org.apache.log4j.*"
        ).map(Assembly.Rule.ExcludePattern.apply)
    super.assembly
  }
```

but when I run `SparkSample.assembly2` it still gets a full assembly and not a filtered one. Seems like overriding `ivyDeps` et. al. in a Task does not work.

Is this possible in `mill`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override defs in a tasks. Just locally defining some `ivyDeps` and `compileIvyDeps` will not magically make `super.assembly` using them.

Of course you can create that task by looking how `super.assembly` is defined in `JavaModule`, but you will end up copying and adapting a lot more targets (`upstreamAssembly`, `upstreamAssemblyClasspath`, `transitiveLocalClasspath`, and so on) and make your buildfile hard to read.

A better way would be to make the lighter dependencies and assembly rules the default and move the creation of the standalone JAR into a sub module.

```scala
import mill._, scalalib._
import mill.modules.Assembly

object SparkSample extends ScalaModule { outer =>
  def scalaVersion = "2.12.10"
  def scalacOptions =
    Seq("-encoding", "utf-8", "-explaintypes", "-feature", "-deprecation")

  def ivySparkDeps = Agg(
    ivy"org.apache.spark::spark-sql:2.4.5"
      .exclude("org.slf4j" -> "slf4j-log4j12"),
    ivy"org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.16",
    ivy"org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.16"
  )

  def ivyDeps = Agg(
    ivy"com.lihaoyi::upickle:0.9.7"
  )

  def compileIvyDeps = ivySparkDeps

  def assemblyRules =
    Assembly.defaultRules ++
      Seq(
        "scala/.*",
        "org.slf4j.*",
        "org.apache.log4j.*"
      ).map(Assembly.Rule.ExcludePattern.apply)

  object standalone extends ScalaModule {
    def scalaVersion = outer.scalaVersion
    def moduleDeps = Seq(outer)
    def ivyDeps = outer.ivySparkDeps
  }
}
```

To create a Spark Cluster JAR run: `mill SparkSample.assembly`

To create a standalone JAR run: `mill SparkSample.standalone.assembly`

To create both, you simply run: `mill __.assembly`

Comment: I had to add

    "def finalMainClass = T { 'com.example.SparkSample' }"

to "standalone" to allow to run "mill SparkSample.standalone.run".

(Now I need to figure out how mill would add the main class to the standalone.assembly manifest file, then all works as I wanted)

Comment: That's because `finalMainClass` is not used for `assembly`. If you use `mainClass` (or `finalMainClassOpt`) it works as expected.